# i want to find the count of specific number in whole table?

Tags: postgresql

in a table, there can be 200 rows and 200 columns, I want to find the count of the number 5 in the whole table and not specifically in a column.

Comment: More often than not, this indicates a bad database design - those 200 columns should probably be rows.

Answer (score 0):

I do agree with *a_horse_with_no_name* this smells badly of a design mistake, so you might want to reevaluate your table structure.

Putting that aside there are mutliple ways to achieve this.
I offer the following two:

```sql
select 
  count(
    case col1 
      when 5 then 1
      else null
    end 
  )
  +
  count(
    case col2 
      when 5 then 1
      else null
    end 
  )
  +
  count(
    case col3 
      when 5 then 1
      else null
    end 
  )
from demo
```

```sql
select 
    count(col) 
from 
(
  select col1 col from demo
  union all
  select col2 from demo
  union all 
  select col3 from demo
) x
where col = 5
```

Of course, I limited myself to 3 columns instead of 200 :-)

See this [DB fiddle for a working sample](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jZs44tzcahjHSDr7oWJpCA/0).